# Bugzilla web does not render css and images properly

Tags: css, bugzilla

I've installed bugzilla version 5.1.1 on my Windows 10 machine. I get the home page without loading any css or image files.

[image: Web page]

[image]

This is the error msg in chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem with Bugzilla 5.0.3 on Apache 2.4, Active Perl, windows 7, MySQL.
I fixed by, finding all .htaccess files in bugzilla directory.

## Don't allow people to retrieve non-cgi executable files or our private data

```
    <FilesMatch (\.pm|\.pl|\.tmpl|localconfig.*)$>
      <IfModule mod_version.c>    <= remove
        <IfVersion < 2.4>           <= remove   
          Deny from all          <= remove
        </IfVersion>               <= remove
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>         <= remove 
          Require all denied
        </IfVersion>               <= remove
     </IfModule>                  <= remove
     <IfModule !mod_version.c>    <= remove
       Deny from all              <= remove
     </IfModule>                  <= remove  
   </FilesMatch>
```

Seems the code for checking Apache version not work and Apache do not accept the "Deny" keyword.  Then the web server access to files under this directly all denied.

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable the **mod_version** module in your Apache server, by deleting the # sign in the front of the following line in the **http.conf** file:

```
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
```

Then restart your Apache server.

Comment: This only applies if module_version isn't compiled into your version of apache.